# How do I create content during site installation?

Tags: nodes, installation

As part of Drupal 8 site install/deploy, I want to create content so that the site is functional and ready to use.

For example, whenever I install the site, there should be a home page node created.

How do I create content during site installation?

Comment: The best way is to create a profile install, here is an example of profile install come with drupal check `core/profiles/demo_umami`

Comment: Also have a look at `hook_install_tasks ` to understand how you can create your own custom form, batch process or a callback function as part of your install process.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/8.2.x

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways in Drupal 8 to manage site default content:

1. [Default content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) module allows to export/import content via `drush` and store the content in the structure similar to config in Drupal core.
2. [Umami](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/8.8.4/core/profiles/demo_umami/modules/demo_umami_content) profile in Drupal core has a custom importer which loads the content stored in CSV to be important as part of module install.
3. [Migrate CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv) plugin allows to important the content from CSV using Drupal core [migration API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview).
4. [Single File Components](https://www.drupal.org/project/sfc) could be used to provide content with components.